# Swift popupView not working (2 didMoveToParentViewController view exist)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a 3 swipe ViewController created with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s)
So, HomeViewController is the controller of those 3 views.

the code is

```
Class HomeViewController //......
func prepareScrollView(){

let V1 : FirstViewController = FirstViewController(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: nil)

let V2 : SecondViewController = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController",bundle: nil)

let V3 : ThirdViewController = ThirdViewController(nibName: "ThirdViewController",bundle: nil)

self.addChildViewController(V1)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V2)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
V2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.addChildViewController(V3)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V3.view)
V3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

var V2Frame : CGRect = V1.view.frame
V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
V2.view.frame = V2Frame


var V3Frame : CGRect = V3.view.frame
V3Frame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
V3.view.frame = V3Frame

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, self.view.frame.size.height)
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width,y : self.view.frame.height)

 }
```

In the SecondViewController, I have create a button to show the a pop up view but it is not working. **I think the reason is there are 2 `didMoveToParentViewController` is existed**

SecondVC:

```
PopButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingUpView), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func settingUpView(){

print("touched")

let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopUpView") as! PoPViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)  
}
```

**When I click to the button it only show the `print` but nothing had popped up, may I ask how do I fix the issue?**

Answer (score -1):

```
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
```

The code above is not right.
self.view.frame.origin is not CGPointZero.

Comment: For critique, use comments. Don't post it as an answer.